# 3d object identification: a formula for numeric identification of shapes.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am not from mathematics fields, but I an working on a monograph for software engineering and I am looking for references related to the following problem:

Considering for example a set of 3d primitive shapes like: sphere, cube, pyramid, torus, cylinder. Using properties like number of vertex, edges, faces, volume perimeter and maybe ratio and proportions... are there studies related to formulas allowing the numeric identification of shapes? a constant that repeats in every shape? 
I am sorry if this is a silly question, but I am not having success finding papers related to this subject.

Comment: You mean like [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) or [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) ?

Comment: Hi Lucian, yes, but something that would consider other parameter like being able to differentiate a primitive cube from a cube that had one of its faces with some degrees rotated, or some edges with different sizes for example. 
 Suppose a formula to generate a specific number for a 3d geometric shape and this number could be used to identify this specifc geometric 3d shape independent from its size for example. Are you aware of any work related to this problem?